# Wrong date time under 2000

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have a problem with format date when i set birthday 1 jan 2000 the touch button done it set on text field 1 jan 1999. I set region on device is Denmark.
Here is my code:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterForDisplay = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
 dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
 [dateFormatterForDisplay setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, YYYY"];
 self.birthdayPicker.date = birthday;
 _birthday = birthday;
 self.birthdayTxt.text = [dateFormatterForDisplay stringFromDate:_birthday];
```

Someone guy help me to solve this bug that help me save a ton of time in my life. Thanks.

Comment: DateFormat for `year` is `yyyy` not `YYYY`, so you dateFormat should be `MMMM dd, yyyy`

Comment: YYYY is Week based calendar. For actual calendar, use yyyy

Comment: I try to change that to yyyy but it still error

Answer (score 3):

change your date format year is **yyyy** not **YYYY**

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterForDisplay = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatterForDisplay.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormatterForDisplay.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[dateFormatterForDisplay setDateFormat:@"d MMM yyyy"]; // customize the format
NSDate *setCurrentDate = [dateFormatterForDisplay dateFromString:@"1 jan 2000"];

NSLog(@"date ==%@", [dateFormatterForDisplay stringFromDate:setCurrentDate]);
```

**output as**

[image]

**updated answer**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterForDisplay = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatterForDisplay.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormatterForDisplay.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[dateFormatterForDisplay setDateFormat:@"d MMM yyyy"];
NSDate *setCurrentDate = [dateFormatterForDisplay dateFromString:@"1 jan 2000"];
 [dateFormatterForDisplay setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"]; // if you want this use like MMMM dd, yyyy
NSLog(@"date ==%@", [dateFormatterForDisplay stringFromDate:setCurrentDate]);
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: @CuongNguyen - wat the input and what the ouput you expect

Comment: I expect that like jan 1, 2000

Comment: @CuongNguyen it not about the order, but you should not use `YYYY` but `yyyy` so you use `MMMM dd, yyyy`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Here is input "po _birthday
2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0000". And I set region of my device to Denmark. The text field return januar 01, 1999

Comment: _birthday is nsdate , nsdate always in irregular format, if you want to access the correct use this  [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:NSLocaleIdentifier]];

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting this:

```
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

try to use :

```
      [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:NSLocaleIdentifier]];
```

It will set your local time zone from device

Comment: It's not an issue of Timezone. What timezone offsets date by a whole year? It's just that OP has an issue in his date format.